# Returning dynamically allocated char array from multiple threads and deallocating the memory inside main in c

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have created an array of threads and changing the global variables based on some conditions in the isSetFunc(). while returning the dynamically allocated character array and printing it in the main it only prints the last thread result in the main function and also while deallocating the memory inside the main function that was created inside the thread didn't get deallocated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER 10

int gset;
int gnot_set;

pthread_mutex_t glock;


void *SetFunc(void *args){
    char* string = (char *)calloc(BUFFER, sizeof(char));

    int* arg = (int *) args;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&glock);
    if(*arg < 4){
        gset++;
        strcpy(string, "True\n");
    }
    else{
        gnot_set++;
        strcpy(string, "False");
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&glock);

    return string;
}


int main()
{

    int threadRes,
    i = 0;
    void* pResult;
    pthread_t* thread;

    pthread_mutex_init(&glock, NULL);

    thread = (pthread_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*(10));

    while (i < 10)
    {
        threadRes = pthread_create(&(thread[i]), NULL, &isSetFunc, &i);
        if(threadRes != 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error occured while creating a thread\n");
            return -1;
        }
        pthread_join(thread[i], &pResult);
        i++;
    }

    printf("In main thread: %s\n", (char *)pResult);

    printf("\ng_set = %d\ngnot_set = %d\n", gset, gnot_set);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&glock);

    free(thread);
    free(pResult);

    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
==387== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==387== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==387== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==387== Command: ./a.out
==387==
==387== error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block
In main thread: False

g_set = 4
gnot_set = 4
==387==
==387== HEAP SUMMARY:
==387==     in use at exit: 70 bytes in 7 blocks
==387==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 4 frees, 4,512 bytes allocated
==387==
==387== LEAK SUMMARY:
==387==    definitely lost: 70 bytes in 7 blocks
==387==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==387==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==387==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==387==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==387== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==387==
==387== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==387== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your threads are running one at a time, so you're only printing the final result after all threads are run.

The `pthread_join` function causes the calling thread to wait until the specified thread returns.  Since you're calling `pthread_join` right after `pthread_create`, this means you create a thread, wait for it to finish, then create a new thread, etc.

The memory leak you're seeing is because every thread is returning malloced memory but you only free it once at the end of the program, so you're only freeing the last thread's result.

You want two loops: one for creating the threads and one for joining them.  The second loop should call `pthread_join`, lock the mutux, print the values, unlock, then `free` the return value.

Comment: After doing this also there is a loss of some bytes while running the code on Valgrind.